# Format string attack in NSString

Tags: nsstring, string-formatting, code-injection

I have read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/ValidatingInput.html

However, I am unclear on how to avoid format String attacks with user entered data when using `NSString +stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this vulnerability is exploited is by accepting a format string from a user.

For example, take this code. You have a simple view with a button and a text field, allowing user input to be NSLogged.

```
- (void)buttonTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"User says:");
    NSLog(self.userInputTextField);
}
```

What will happen if the user types `crash! %@` into the box and and taps the button? Well, they'll probably get a crash. But as the linked article explains, the user can use this attack vector to manipulate the stack and cause your application to execute arbitrary code. What if this string came in from an internet-based attacker?

You should **never** allow user input to be used as a format string. The secure way to write this code is as follows.

```
- (void)buttonTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"User says: %@", self.userInputTextField);
}
```

This way, if the user types `crash! %@`, you'll see this printed:

```
User says: crash! %@
```